# Can Visual Studio require a work item be linked to a git commit?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem

Using Visual Studio 2015, TFS 2015 and Git, is there any way to enforce or remind me to link a work item on check-in? Or is it possible in newer versions of VS / TFS? VS extension?

What I want:

[image: Visual Studio Changes window]

This has been asked before, but not in the past 2 years.

I will persue this option if there really isn't anything else available: Write a plugin: http://almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you just want enforce **commit policy** in TFS with GIT repository, this is still **not supported out of the box** currently .

It is however on the product teams backlog and you could only use the Tfs-Git *ProcessEvent hook* just as the [blog](http://almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/) posted in your question for now.

Comment: The link is broken. Could you provide another link ?

Comment: You can see the linked blog post at [the web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20171014025723/almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/)

Answer (score 3):

You can require it as part of a pull request. The Visual Studio integration you see for TFVC is implemented in the form of a source control checkin policy, of which there is no equivalent for Git. Use pull requests, instead.

I'd recommend against writing server-side TFS plugins in almost every case; they represent a potentially big barrier to upgrades down the line, and totally block you from ever pursuing moving to VS Team Services unless you stop using the plugin. It's better to find solutions that don't involve checkin policies.

Comment: We do use pull requests, but we would also like all commits to have a work item.

Answer (score -1):

Your TFS Admin can perform this (or someone with administrative permissions). The change can either be done for the collection or for a specific project. This means that everyone will get the policy warning. The VS-TFS Power Tools add-on will be required.

In VS > Team > Team Project (Collection) Settings > Source Control... > Check In Policy > Add > Work Items

[image]

Comment: Will this work with git repositories? We are not using TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control).

Comment: From my experience, it will work in VS with the normal TFS source control. When you're interacting with a git repo in a different IDE like SourceTree, it won't enforce it. I am confident that it will work in VS with a git repo (I haven't tried it).

Comment: This question is about Visual Studio 2015, TFS 2015 and Git. If you're using TFS and not GIT, then you are using TFVC as your source control. I wouldn't say TFVC is the "normal" one - Team Services (cloud version of TFS) now has Git as the default source control. When I select Team Project Collection Settings -> Source Control, it opens as shown above with a project in TFVC, but gives an error with a Git project.

Comment: "Normal" as in it was the standard built-in version control with TFS for a very long time until git was integrated.