# How to force everyone on git commit from Visual Studio 2022 to specify work item?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

People committing code to ADO GIT from Visual Studio without specifying related ADO work item. Similar to [Can Visual Studio require a work item be linked to a git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702825/can-visual-studio-require-a-work-item-be-linked-to-a-git-commit) - but we are using GIT in ADO.

Nothing, not seeing how to set it up so it's mandatory

Comment: Are you using Pull Requests? IMHO it's easier (and generally better) to require work items be associated with a PR instead of every commit.

Comment: Not using PRs at this point.

Comment: In general, you can let people do whatever they want on personal branches, but lock down when they are ready to merge those personal branches into a shared branch. AzDO has excellent options for controlling what is merged in with PRs. One of those controls is requiring work items to be associated with a PR. The problem with doing it at the commit level is every single pushed commit gets associated with a work item, even if you rebase, amend, and delete test branches, the commits persist forever and the work items can get polluted. (You can manually clean them up but it's tedious...)

Comment: I think the takeaway of my previous comment is, perhaps this would be enough to push you over the edge to consider using PRs... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a CI job that checks each commit (or just one of the commits, if you prefer that) for a specific entry matching a regular expression.  Git provides a way to include such information as trailers, which are colon-separated lines at the end of the commit message, and provides the `git interpret-trailers` tool to extract this information from the commit message (or, really, from any text).

[The Git FAQ is clear](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks) that you can't use hooks on the client side to do this because they can be bypassed.  You can, of course, provide an optional set of pre-commit hooks for people to use if they want to, but you shouldn't force them to do so since that can break a variety of more advanced workflows.

Typically, the way you'll process commits in CI is with `git rev-list --format=%B BASE...HEAD`, where `BASE` and `HEAD` are the base branch (usually the main branch) and `HEAD` is the head of the pull request.  You can then parse the data to extract each entry and pass it through `git interpret-trailers` to see if it has the data you want.